# Node background-image not working (Only images from Flickr display)

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am having trouble getting the background-image node property to work.

I am simply using the "Images & breadthfirst layout" demo as a test example (located at https://gist.github.com/maxkfranz/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5), but I cannot even get that to work.

In the demo, within the 'code.js' file, if I change any image path to anything other than staticflickr, the image will not display. For instance:

If I change

```
.selector('#bird')
  .css({
    'background-image': 'https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7272/7633179468_3e19e45a0c_b.jpg'
  })
```

to

```
.selector('#bird')
  .css({
    'background-image': 'http://astromatrix.org/Content/Images/Objects/Bird.jpg'
  })
```

The image shows up blank grey in the graph (as shown in the attached image).

I have tried local files, multiple other images hosted on different sites, and the only images I can get to work are from flickr.

Am I completely missing something?

Thanks in advance

[Blank image for bird when I change the image URL from flickr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzAWv.png)

Comment: I got 404 for the image you put as example. Did you check that in Network from developer tool?

Comment: @leo.fcx sorry, I had used the wrong image as example.  You are correct that the image I used first was giving a 404 error, so I changed it to a working example that still produces a blank node in the graph.

Comment: @leo.fcx, I'm not sure I know what you are referring to when asking if I checked the Network from developer tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use images that you own on your own server.  You can't use an image if the server doesn't send back the proper headers.

Make sure to refer to the [log in the debug console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/):

`Access to Image at 'http://astromatrix.org/Content/Images/Objects/Bird.jpg' from origin 'http://astromatrix.org' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.`